# Can't access internal SD card on my phone

Tags: internal-storage

I recently upgraded my phone to android lolipop with cm 12 while doing so i first cleared all the data and also deleted my partition, now after installing lolipop i Can't access my internal storage on d phone but I can see it in the file manager .Next when i download apps from play store an error shows insufficient storage available, but I have ample space on my device,internal SD and ext sd. And when I tried to create a SD card partion via cwm 6.0.5 , the option of SD partion was not there in advanced option.please help 
I have a Samsung galaxy note n 7000

Comment: You have mounted a partition that shouldn't have been mounted, which caused it to swap with another partition for internal storage. Figure out which partition was mounted and unmount. You'll probably/maybe/have to re-flash the ROM.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change the USB settings on your phone.  I found the answer [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/6pbWH1yvPMs).

> After you connect your Nexus to your PC/Mac via USB, swipe down on the
>   Notification shade, and select MTP there from the USB options shown.